# How to "debug" StanfordNLP text classifier

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using StanfordNLP to do text classification. I have a training set with two labels: YES and NO. Both labels have more or less the same datums per label (~= 120K).

The problem is that StanfordNLP is misclassifying some text, and I'm not able to identify why. How do I debug it?

My train file look like:

```
YES guarda-roupa/roupeiro 2 portas de correr
YES guarda-roupa/roupeiro 3 portas
YES guarda roupa , roupeiro 3 portas
YES guarda-roupa 4 portas
YES guarda roupa 6p mdf
YES guardaroupas 3 portas
YES jogo de quarto com guarda-roupa 2 portas + cômoda + berço
YES guarda roupa 4pts
NO  base para guarda-sol
NO  guarda-sol alumínio
NO  guarda chuva transparente
NO  coifa guarda po alavanca cambio
NO  lancheira guarda do leao vermelha
NO  hard boiled: queima roupa
NO  roupa nova do imperador
NO  suporte para passar roupa
```

The YES label identifies "guarda roupa" (wardrobe) and NO identifies things that aren't "guarda roupa" but have one or more commons words (such as "guarda chuva" -- umbrella, or "roupa" -- clothes).

I don't know why, but my model insists to classify "guarda roupa" (and its variations such as "guardaroupa", "guarda-roupas", etc) as NO...

How do I debug it? I already double checked my train file in order to see if I misclassified something, introducing an error, but I could not find it...

Any advice is welcome.

**UPDATE 1**

I'm using the following properties in order to control features creation:

```
 useClassFeature=false
 featureMinimumSupport=2
 lowercase=true
 1.useNGrams=false
 1.usePrefixSuffixNGrams=false
 1.splitWordsRegexp=\\s+
 1.useSplitWordNGrams=true
 1.minWordNGramLeng=2
 1.maxWordNGramLeng=5
 1.useAllSplitWordPairs=true
 1.useAllSplitWordTriples=true
 goldAnswerColumn=0
 displayedColumn=1
 intern=true
 sigma=1
 useQN=true
 QNsize=10
 tolerance=1e-4
```

**UPDATE 2**

Searching the API, I discovered that `ColumnDataClassifier` has a method `getClassifier()` that gives access to the underlying `LinearClassifier`, which has a `dump()` method. The dump produces an output that looks like bellow. From API: "`Print all features in the classifier and the weight that they assign to each class.`"

```
                                      YES     NO
1-SW#-guarda-roupa-roupeiro-2portas   0,01    -0,01   
1-ASWT-guarda-roupa-roupeiro          0,19    -0,19
1-SW#-guarda-roupa-roupeiro           0,19    -0,19
```

If I do a `toString()` into `LinearClassifier` it will print:

```
[-0.7, -0.7+0.1): 427.0  [(1-SW#-guarda-roupa-roupeiro-2portas,NO), ...]
[0.6, 0.6+0.1): 427.0  [(1-SW#-guarda-roupa-roupeiro-2portas,YES), ...]
```

Comment: What features are you using for your classifier?  You should look at the weights assigned to the features and what features appear in the misclassified examples.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you should observe that the mere presence of the word "guarda" or "roupa" is not informative in your set up, since it appears in both YES and NO frequently.  If you don't have a feature for the presence of both of those words together, it's not going to learn that those two words together means YES.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp I added some additional info, but I'm not able to interpret the output.